# How to load HTML file AS Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to load a javascript library from outsite my front-end like this:

```
<script async src="https://other-domain.com/AgencySystem/chat/js"></script>
```

But Firefox stop excuting this script because of `https://other-domain.com/AgencySystem/chat/js` return mime-type = text/html

So my question is: How can I run this external HTML file like Javascript file?"

Comment: Are you sure the `src` is a file? Looks like a folder to me.

Comment: Please don't write words in capitalized letters only. This means screaming and it is rude behaviour in any forum on this planet.

Comment: @Michel it return as a javascript file content, it is not a folder sir!